# What is typedef with multiple types to one alias?

Tags: c++, syntax, typedef

What does "
`typedef NOT_LP64(uint16_t) LP64_ONLY(uint32_t) idx_t;`
" mean?

The code is from jdk8, `taskqueue.hpp`.

I don't understand the above syntax.

I find many explanations about `typedef type name`, but they don't explain the above situation.

---

`NOT_LP64` and `LP64_ONLY` are defined in `macro.hpp` file.

```
#ifdef  _LP64
#define LP64_ONLY(code) code
#define NOT_LP64(code)
#else  // !_LP64
#define LP64_ONLY(code)
#define NOT_LP64(code) code
#endif // _LP64
```

Comment: either one of the macros will expand to nothing

Comment: Of `LP64_ONLY` and `NOT_LP64`, one of them will expand to be it's argument and the other will expand to be nothing. You are left with a `typedef` with only one type, and a bit of extra white space.

Comment: I see. `typedef` can expand to nothing. That is the reason. Got it!

Comment: @skytree You misunderstood. Either `NOT_LP64(uint16_t)` *or* `LP64_ONLY(uint32_t)` expand to nothing.

Comment: @skytree: No, a `typedef` cannot be nothing.  Look at it again more carefully.  If `_LP64` is defined, `NOT_LP64(uint16_t)` will be nothing and `LP64_ONLY(uint32_t)` will be `uint32_t`. If `_LP64` is not defined, `NOT_LP64(uint16_t)` will be `uint16_t` and `LP64_ONLY(uint32_t)` will be nothing.  But either way, `idx_t` will be an alias of *something*.

Comment: This question isn't really so much about type aliases as it is about what pre processor macros are and how they behave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you evaluate those macros, then the code will become either

```
typedef uint16_t idx_t;
```

or

```
typedef uint32_t idx_t;
```

depending on the value of `_LP64`. Both of those only have one type.

In general, those macros can be used to only run code in one circumstance or the other. In this specific case, the “code” in question is just a single type.